# Qt(C++) ラベルの点滅を1文字単位でしたい

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Qtのラベルで全体ではなく、指定の文字を点滅させたいのですが何かいい方法は無いでしょうか
ラベル全体を点滅させるのはsetVisible関数をタイマーで呼び出して
true/falseを入れ替えれば簡単にできたのですが
特定の文字を点滅させる方法は無いでしょうか

abcdと言う文字列であれば
3文字目を点滅させたいと言う風にしたいです

Answer (score 2, accepted):

いろんなやり方があると思いますが、点滅させたい文字の色を透明色にしてみるのはどうでしょう。

```
#include <QtWidgets>
  
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        QApplication app(argc, argv);

        QLabel label("abcd");
        label.setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
        label.show();

        QTimer timer;
        QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&label]() {
                static bool visible = true;
                label.setText(visible ? "abcd" : "ab<span style=\"color: transparent\">c</span>d");
                visible = !visible;
        });
        timer.start(1000);
        return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。これでいけそうです。ただ、どちらも<p></p>でくくらないと透明にしたときに微妙に文字がずれるみたいです